# How can I implement path subtraction using RaphaelJS' pathIntersection() method?

Tags: javascript, raphael

Documentation for the method is here: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.pathIntersection

Let's say what I want to do is subtract one path from another. Seems like the return object for pathIntersection() has all the information I need to do this. Is this true? And if so, what's the basic approach?

Comment: Can you provide a conceptual example? If there exists a pentagon with points A,B,C,D,E and a triangle with points B,C,D you would like to have A,E? What if the 2nd shape doesn't entirely match (like a triangle B,C,X)? What would you like the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [parsePathString](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.parsePathString) method for both paths, compare them and create a new path from the points that didn't match..?

Comment: Eric's question covers Raphael path elements, a 2 dimensional shape definition -- not URIs in string form.

Comment: Right, I changed my post & added a request for clarification-comment :P